# Any particular reason for $\Delta x_t=x_t-x_{t-1}$ or $\Delta x_t=x_{t+1}-x_{t}$

Tags: notation, recurrence-relations

I never know whether to define $\Delta x_t$ (change of $x$)as 
$$\Delta x_t=x_t-x_{t-1}$$ or $$\Delta x_t=x_{t+1}-x_{t}$$

Is there any particular reason to choose one over the other?

If it is irrelevant, what is customary to do?

Answer (score 1):

It does not matter at all. It's just a matter of preference. You can switch from one to the other by adjusting the $t$'s as necessary.

Answer (score 1):

It is customary to use $\Delta x_t$ for the "forward difference" $x_{t+1}-x_t$, and when these sorts of questions are asked ([MathWorld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FiniteDifference.html), [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Forward.2C_backward.2C_and_central_differences)), to use $\nabla x_t$ for the "backward difference" $x_t-x_{t-1}$. However, there are exceptions to this usage, such as at [Harvey Mudd's Riemann Sums tutorial page](https://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/riemann_sums/).

I believe the forward difference may be more common, but both are about equally useful (e.g. [Newton's forward difference formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsForwardDifferenceFormula.html) has a [backward difference formulation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/NewtonsBackwardDifferenceFormula.html)).

In my personal opinion, one thing in favor of the forward difference is that if your sequence only goes forward from $x_0$, you can write $\Delta x_0$, but $\nabla x_0$ would require some explanation. The alternative is to keep track of the fact that the lowest allowed index for $\nabla x_i$ is one more than that for $x_i$.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when discussing stochastic processes it is good to use the backward difference $x_t - x_{t-1}$.  The reason would be that, at time $t$, we know the past, but not (yet) the future.  So we know the backward difference $x_t - x_{t-1}$; but the forward difference $x_{t+1}-x_t$ is a random variable that we do not (yet) know.